# Mounted NFS share. Can create folders in file browser, but mkdir doesn't work through terminal

Tags: debian, ubuntu, permissions, nfs

I am sharing a folder from OpenMediaVault 3.0 to Ubuntu using NFS.

It mounts, and I can see the files in it.  I can create folders and copy to the mount through the Ubuntu GUI file browser.

However, if I try to mkdir, cp, or rsync to it, I get "Permission Denied" whether I use sudo or not.

I ensured that the server and client both have the same username, UID and GID.

Do you know why this may be the case?  And how I can mount with full permissions?

```
media@media-vm:~$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          1.6G   10M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda1                       16G  6.8G  8.2G  46% /
tmpfs                          7.9G   16K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                          7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                      7.0T  3.1T  3.6T  47% /7TB
tmpfs                          1.6G  144K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
10.0.1.73:/export/MediaBackup  5.5T  217G  5.2T   4% /mnt/MediaBackup
```

Command to mount:

```
media@media-vm:~$ sudo mount -t nfs 10.0.1.73:/MergerFS/ /mnt/nfs/MergerFS/
```

From nano /etc/exports on OMV3:

```
/export/MediaBackup (fsid=3,rw,subtree_check,secure)
```

Mount information:

```
media@media-vm:~$ ls -ld /mnt/MediaBackup/
drwxrwsr-x 3 root users 4096 May  3 15:42 /mnt/MediaBackup/
```

Copy attempt sudo:

```
media@media-vm:/7TB$ sudo cp -r Movies/ /mnt/MediaBackup 
cp: cannot create directory 'mnt/MediaBackup/Movies': Permission denied
```

Comment: please add example of command you are failing to execute and its output, and the result of `id`

Comment: media@media-vm:/7TB$ sudo cp -r Movies/ /mnt/MediaBackup

cp: cannot create directory 'mnt/MediaBackup/Movies': Permission denied

Comment: @botts what happened when you exeute mkdir? As regular user (without sudo)? What is the output of the command 'id'?